# Transponer en dos rangos, el segundo rango convertir valores en negativo y agregar dos columnas con valores (fecha, tipo)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

me encuentro atorado en lo siguiente, cuento con dos rangos, uno llamado ingresos y el otro egreso:

1. Ambos rangos transponerlos.
2. El rango egresos convertir valores en negativo.
3. A ambos rangos agregarles el valor de la fecha y si es el rango de ingresos agregarle ingreso y si es egreso agregarle egreso.
4. Ambos rangos guardarlos en un objeto para enviarlo a otro sheet.
5. saber total de filas de ambos rangos para para insertar esa cantidad de filas en la nueva sheet.

Hasta el momento he transpuesto ambos con objet.key y los almacene cada rango en un objeto, tenia la idea que después los concatenaría sin embargo me salen 3 corchetes y eso me ha impedido avanzar

```js
function myFunction2() {
  var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
      Sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
      RangeIngresos = Sheet.getRange(2,2,12,7).getValues(),
      RangeEgresos  = Sheet.getRange(15,2,12,12).getValues(),
      LastColum1    = RangeIngresos[0].filter(String).length,
      LastColum2    = RangeEgresos[0].filter(String).length;
   
      var Ingresos = [],
          Egresos  = [];

      Ingresos.push(Object.keys(RangeIngresos[0].filter(String))
      .map(function(columnNumber){
        return RangeIngresos.map(function(row){
          return row[columnNumber];
        });
      }));

      Egresos.push(Object.keys(RangeEgresos[0].filter(String))
      .map(function(Hola){
        return RangeEgresos.map(function(hellow){
          return hellow[Hola];
        });
      }));

Sheet.getRange(30,1,LastColum1,12).setValues(Ingresos[0]);
Sheet.getRange(30+LastColum1,1,LastColum2,12).setValues(Egresos[0]);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la siguiente función para transponer:

```
function transpose(a) {
  return Object.keys(a[0]).map(function (c) { return a.map(function (r) { return r[c]; });});
}
```

Tomado de la respuesta de Mogsdad a [Google Spreadsheet Script - How to Transpose / Rotate Multi-dimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16621470/1595451)

Una forma de aplicar lo anterior es

```
var Ingresos = transpose(LastColum1),
    Egresos = transpose(LastColum2)
```

Nótese que el ejemplo hace uso de `push`. Esto es lo que está causando el que tengas "tres corchetes", es decir estar insertando un Array de Array (Array "bidimencional") en un Array (con lo cual creas un Array "tridimencional").

Si aplica lo anterior en el código incluido en la pregunta, en llos `setValues` de las últimas líneas  en lugar de usar `Ingresos[0]` y `Egresos[0]` deberás usar `Ingresos` y `Egresos`

Comment: Estoy con la idea que fue lo que use, utilice push para guardarlo en un array lo transpuesto pero creo que el detalle es que me sale con 3 corchetes y eso me me ha obstaculizado concatenar con otro rango.

Comment: Agregué un ejemplo de como puedes usarlo.